# Retouch an image pattern so it may be used as a repeating background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, patterns

I have the following image pattern:

[image: Pattern]

If I repeat it as a web page background the variation in color and brightness are very visible at the tile edges.

[image]

What can I do to retouch this image so the color and brightness are vertically consistent and unnoticeable as a repeating background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a few ways you could approach it, but I think the easiest is to convert a copy of the image to greyscale, then make it really high contrast by using levels (clicking auto should do it).

[image]

[image]

From there, you can make a gradient selection of the bottom portion (hit `q` to enter `quickmask`, press `g` to select the gradient tool, make sure you have a black and white gradient selected, then draw from the top of your image to the bottom and press `q` to exit `quickmask`).

And now, you can use `levels` to adjust the bottom part of the image. I’m using a levels adjustment layer.

[image]

We now have a high contrast, version that will loop correctly, but is the wrong colour. A `gradient map` can be used to accurately choose replacement colours.

[image]

It now repeats pretty well.

[image]

For even better results, more care could be taken at the greyscale stage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the burn tool to make the bottom part darker. I would use the Image you cropped out here to make the "burn" to fit and then crop it a use it. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way would involve doubling the height of the image, copying and transform flip vertial and put it above it but that does mess with the pattern abit giving it that mirror look. you can also google for seamless pattern photoshop which will have you duplicating the layer and positioning it 50% and feathering between them. the problem is you have a vertical gradient running through your pattern, perhaps there is better source material or use one of the billions of paisley patterns you can find online and just do a fill of that color and set the mode to hue or use a gradient map good luck